# Combine data and non data rows in SQL

Tags: sql, join

Table : Mark M [Id, Subject, Mark]

Test Student Ids: 100, 101

Requirement: We need mark of both students of subject 'Maths'. 
Condition: Student (101) was absent for Maths exam. So there wont be any record in Mark table for the student 101.

Expected Result:

```
Student ID Subject Mark
100        Maths   45
101        Maths   0
```

I.e. We need to add an additional row with Subject=Maths and Mark=0 for student 101

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using left join

```
select * from students a left join marks b
on a.studentid=b.studentid
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use left  join

```
 select  s.*, m.*
 from  student s 
 left join Mark  m  on m.Id = s.id
```

left join retrive row also if the values don't match

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple subjects and are only interested in math, then you need to be careful about filtering:

```
select s.*, 'Maths' as subject, coalesce(m.mark, 0) as mark
from student s left join
     mark m
     on m.Id = s.id and m.subject = 'Maths';
```